# Deleting .sqlite file from project folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm creating an application, that needs an SQLite Database for storing settings that the user made, so it will be remembered next time the application gets started.

I know that there are ways to create a file in that the project folder using this way:

```
string path = string.Format(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\PigeonBackup.sqlite");

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(string.Format(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\PigeonBackup.sqlite"));
```

But I'm debugging this application a lot, and it would be useful to have something like a button, that will delete the .sqlite file from my project folder. Is there some sort of class that can help me with my problem?

Comment: Keep a command prompt open with the appropriate delete command given? ALT + TAB, UP, ENTER, ALT + TAB, done.

Comment: isn't there a part of code, which achieves this?

Comment: I 'm not sure I follow. Your problem is not how to delete the file, it's how to automate the deletion so that it's convenient, right?

Comment: No, it is how to delete a file(.sqlite) from my project folder, I know how to get the path of the file I want to delete, but don't how how to actually delete it

Comment: Eh... [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **delete all the files with Extension** `.sqllite` then try  the below code :

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.sqlite")
                     .Where(p => p.Extension == ".sqlite").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
  try
  {
    file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    File.Delete(file.FullName);
  }
  catch { }
```

If you want to **delete Particular file** then try the Below Code :

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\PigeonBackup.sqlite");
System.IO.File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: You should not recommend `string.Format` for joining paths (even if the question used it). `Path.Combine` is the method to use.

Comment: @Mobstaa : Read this blog : http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/systemiopath.html .. You will get understand...